# Як перекласти українською мовою tourist landmark/site/attraction?

Tags: from-english, словотворення, переклади, новотвори

Як зазначено у заголовку, шукаю як перекласти українською мовою *tourist landmark/site/attraction*? Укрвікі перекладає слово *landmark* як *[орієнтир](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80)* (тобто виходить *туристичний орієнтир*), а *tourist attraction/site* як *[туристична пам'ятка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)*, але обидва варіанта видаються слабенькими.

Ймовірно, мені знадобиться допомога [словоковалів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) які б вигадали якийсь новотвір, адже поточні переклади які я знайшов мене не влаштовують.

Comment: Можливо, варто пояснити, що означає «видаються слабенькими». Окрім того, упевнений, що туристичні агенції вже давно знайшли відповідники до цих термінів. :) Як-то *туристичні місця, визначні місця, історичні/архітектурні/культурні пам'ятки, атракціони* у залежності від характеру об'єкту, про який йдеться.

Comment: Словоковалі живуть на словотворі https://slovotvir.org.ua/ На цьому сайті це "неформат".

Comment: Є подібне запитання: [«Чи існує однозначний переклад слова „достопримечательность“?»](/q/5812), там пропонують _показне місце_ і ще інші варіанти в коментарях.

Comment: Як згадали їнші, кажуть "визначна пам'ятка", "визначне місце" для місць, які варто відвідати. Хоча в такій сполуці нема прямого стосунку до туризму, значеннєво вона близька. Шодо новотворів, то на думку спадає "привабливе місце", "туристська/туристична/мандрівнича привабливість". "Туристське/туристичне місце" також доволі зрозумілий і вдалий переклад для "tourist site". Особисто гадаю, шо ліпше є вживати "туристський" за "туристичний", бо перше краще відбиває питомий словотвір (творене прямо від "турист" проти "туристика").

Comment: Буде залежати від контексту. А саме від властивостей об'єкту, про який хочете повідомити. landmark - мітка, позначення на мапі.
site - видовище, краєвид.
attraction - визначне місце.